# How do I write a recursive insertion sort?

Tags: ruby, recursion

```
def recursive_insert(arr)
  return arr if arr.size<=1
  recursive_insert(arr[0,arr.size-1])
  i=arr.size-1
  while arr[i-1]>arr[i] and i>0
    arr[i],arr[i-1] = arr[i-1],arr[i]
    i-=1
  end
  arr
end
arr=[5,4,3,2,6,1]
x=recursive_insert(arr)
puts x.inspect
```

This doesn't work. I suspect that Ruby has a pass by reference mechanism, which prevents my `arr` variable being updated for each recursive call.

How do I solve this? I have so many difficulties writing a recursive function in Ruby.

Comment: Ruby has no pointers, thus no pass by reference. An array sorting algorithm is already implement, you can use that. If you are trying to implement a sorting algorithm yourself why not do it in C/C++. Ruby is meant to be easy and use was it has built in.

Comment: @KassymDorsel yea, I think scripting languages like Python and Ruby are good for implementing higher level data structure and algorithms but not low level ones. I prefer to use C for detailed implement. I just want to test my understanding of ruby by working out couple data structure and algo problems. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
arr[0, arr.size - 1]
```

returns a copy of part of `arr` and changes to that copy will not be reflected in `arr`. So, your recursive step does nothing useful and your method is equivalent to this:

```
def recursive_insert(arr)
  return arr if arr.size<=1
  i=arr.size-1
  while arr[i-1]>arr[i] and i>0
    arr[i],arr[i-1] = arr[i-1],arr[i]
    i-=1
  end
  arr
end
```

and that gets the 1 in the right place and that's all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ya, this is also the reason I suspected. You know anyway to work around?

Comment: @zsljulius: Pass first and last indices along with the array. Or build a class that wraps the array and maintains the "pointerness" of the array segment.

Answer (score -1):

```
void insertInOrder( int * a , int start ,int element)
{
    if(start < 0)
    {
        a[start + 1] = element;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(element < a[start])
        {
            a[start+ 1] = a[start];
            insertInOrder(a,start-1,element);
        }
        else
            a[start + 1] = element;
    }
}
void recursiveInsertionSort(int * a , int start , int end)
{
    if(start >= end)
        return;
    else
    {
        insertInOrder(a,start,a[start+1]);
        recursiveInsertionSort(a,start+1,end);
    }
}
void main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int a[SIZE] = {9,8,7,6,10};
    recursiveInsertionSort(a,0,SIZE-1);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

> This is recursive implementation of insertion sort in c++